# Obtaining PKCS7 data length with OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, pkcs#7

I have some PKCS7 data which I can read like this with OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i -inform der -in data.dat
0:d=0  hl=4 l=16208 cons: SEQUENCE
4:d=1  hl=2 l=    9 prim:  OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedData
.. more ..
```

I can load it in code like so:

```
// buf contains the raw data, len the length
BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(buf, len);

PKCS7 *pkcs7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(bio, NULL);
if (!pkcs7) {
    // die
}
printf("Success!");
```

This works fine and I can successfully obtain signer information etc.  However I'd like to obtain the length value as parsed from the input data.  In my example this was 16208, seen in the second line of the ASN1 output.

I noticed there is a `length` attribute to the PKCS7 structure (see `include/openssl/pkcs7.h`) but `pkcs7->length` is always zero when I print it.

How can I obtain the length of the overall sequence which contains PKCS7 signed data?